# Centroid for a rectangular section inclined at an angle theta

Tags: geometry, formula, angle, centroid

How to find Centroid for a rectangular section inclined at an angle theta? Is there any general formula available?

Comment: You might consider posting on math.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 1):

Centroid of a rectangle is situated at intersection of it's diagonals (or arithmetic mean of all vertices). So it is enough to find vertice coordinates after inclination

Answer (score 1):

Centroid of a rectangle does not changes, after inclination.
Only the co-ordinates of a Rectangle changes with the following equation.

```
 x′=xcosθ − ysinθ 
 y′=xsinθ + ycosθ
```

where,

```
    (x,y)-initial co-ordinates of rectangle.
    (x',y')-final co-ordinates of rectangle.
    θ-angle of inclination.
```

Refer [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166886/centroid-for-a-rectangular-section-inclined-at-an-angle-theta) for detail.